# How to group dates by year in pandas timeseries?

Tags: time-series, pandas-groupby

I have the following data for AAPL:

```
    High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                        
1987-12-31  1.535714    1.495536    1.517857    1.500000    29400000.0  1.200883
1988-01-04  1.598214    1.508929    1.526786    1.598214    82600000.0  1.279513
1988-01-05  1.651786    1.580357    1.642857    1.593750    77280000.0  1.275938
1988-01-06  1.607143    1.562500    1.607143    1.562500    67200000.0  1.250920
1988-01-07  1.598214    1.517857    1.553571    1.589286    53200000.0  1.272364
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2007-12-24  28.475714   27.827143   27.861429   28.400000   120050700.0 24.785059
2007-12-26  28.708570   28.117144   28.430000   28.421429   175933100.0 24.803761
2007-12-27  28.994286   28.257143   28.421429   28.367144   198881900.0 24.756376
2007-12-28  28.794285   28.125713   28.655714   28.547142   174911800.0 24.913471
2007-12-31  28.642857   28.250000   28.500000   28.297142   134833300.0 24.695290
5044 rows × 6 columns
```

What i want to do is add another column which will group all the data by month and year. This way i can run an operation on just months or come year(s). The Date is already in datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the year and month and put them in two columns "year" and "month" with:

```
df['year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
```

If you want a single column "year_and_month" you can use:

```
df['year_and_month'] = df['Date'].dt.year.astype('str') + '-' + df['Date'].dt.month.astype('str')
```

Comment: I forgot to mention but i had tried `data['year'] = data['Date'].dt.year
` but since the datetime is index(i suppose that is the problem) `Date` i get the following error: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: You can use ``df['year'] = df.index.year`` and ``df['month'] = df.index.month`` instead.